# Javascript for defining a variable from a clicked on list element's id

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm looking to define a variable:

```
var alumniName = // id from a list ( example: <li id="JoeJohnson">Joe Johnson</li> ).
```

I want the variable to match what a visitor clicks on. 
(example:

```
<li id="JoeJohnson">Joe Johnson</li>  
// when a visitor clicks on the name Joe Johnson... the variable = JoeJohnson

<li id="FredSmith">Fred Smith</li>
// when a visitor clicks on the name Fred Smith... the variable = FredSmith
```

etc... )

Any help is much appreciated -Thanks-

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Do you use a JavaScript library? (Btw your question is super-basic. You probably should read a tutorial on JavaScript event handling first.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
HTML:

```
<ul>
<li data-name='Joe Johnson'>Joe Johnson</li>
<li data-name='Fred Smith'>Fred Smith</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript (to be called on body load):

```
var alumniName = '';
var liElems = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

for (var i=0; i<liElems.length; i++)
{
    liElems[i].onclick = function(){  
        alumniName = this.getAttribute('data-name');
        alert(alumniName);
    };

}
```

Comment: Another question related - how would I pass this information to a form that is on another web page? -The 1st webpage grabs the name and then passes it on to the second web page which holds the form.

Comment: Options: 1. You can POST values from the first page to the other. 2. Assuming that the other webpage is on the same domain, If the other page opens in a new window, then you can access the variables from the first page by using opener.alumniName or opener.someVar. 3. If the values you are sending to the next page are short then you can even append them as a query string in the next page's url. 4. You could even have 2 forms on one page, hide the second one by default and show it after the first form is done. You can easily populate the values in the second form since its on the same page :)

Answer (score 2):

we had to make some assumptions about your setup... but take a peak here and see if this makes sense. no library required.

HTML

```
<ul id="myList">
<li data-name='Joe Johnson'>Joe Johnson</li>
<li data-name='Fred Smith'>Fred Smith</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
var list = document.getElementById('myList'),
    alumniName;

Array.prototype.forEach.call(list.getElementsByTagName('li'), function(item) {
    item.onclick = function() {
        alumniName = this.getAttribute('data-name');
        // or if you feel you still want to use ID's to store the values (spaces are not allowed) you can just ref this.id
    };
});
```

Comment: If you read Bergi's vs mine - you will notice the use of an event listener... what event listeners do is allow you to add multiple listeners to the same event. if you over write the event `.onclick = function` then you have over written all listeners on said element / event

Comment: you forgot a .getElementsByTagName("li") somewhere, didn't you?

Comment: shit yes I did. corrected (albeit not the best way to correct it :P )

Answer (score 1):

You can only set a variable to something related to a click when the click happens. Use an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener):

```
var recentClickedId = null; // init, nothing clicked on now
// let this happen onload, i.e. when the DOM is available:
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    var el = event.target;
    if (el.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "li")
         recentClickedId = el.getAttribute("id");
}, false);
```

Comment: this will fail in IE... and i'm pretty sure Opera?? document.body is not cross compat (FYI for the OP - otherwise good answer)

Comment: Before you get me wrong: i'm not saying you should provide the cross compat version. the OP can do some work... however it is always nice to mention that he will need to look into it.

Comment: Whut, IE does not know [document.body](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-56360201)? Opera surely does...

Comment: lol ok well i'm just crazy then. now I do know IE8< does not recognize addEventListener... but like I said. moreso a FYI - i think everyone at this point knows what you're doing.